# Trigger a function when value change using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to trigger a function when user select other value from a combobox `<select>`

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content" id="appGradeHorariaCompleta">
   <select class="form-control m-b" data-bind="options: Curriculos,optionsText:'Text',optionsValue:'Value',optionsCaption:'Selecione', value: CurriculoSelected, event:{ change: $parent.CurriculosChanged}"></select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function PainelViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Curriculos = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.CurriculosChanged = (function (curriculo) {
        console.debug(curriculo);
    });
}

function CurriculoViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(0);
    self.Value = ko.observable('');
    self.Selected = ko.observable(0);
}
...GET DATA...
...
..
.
$(data.CurriculoComboBox).each(function (index, item) {
    var model = new CurriculoViewModel();
    model.myvalues = item.myValues;
    painelVM.Curriculos().push(model);
});

ko.applyBindings(painelVM, document.getElementById("appGradeHorariaCompleta"));
```

What I want is when value change in the combobox I want to get this parameter to bind another function.

But in the way I've done, I got an error:

```
 Unable to process binding "event: function (){return { change:$parent.HabilitacoesCursosChanged} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe not work, so I still use `event: {change: $parent.CurriculosChanged}`

So, using ideia from siddhearth to get I get the value selected from my var, I can get the new value changing the `$parent` for `$root`

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control m-b" data-bind="options: Curriculos,optionsText:'Text',optionsValue:'Value',optionsCaption:'Selecione', value: CurriculoSelected, event:{ change: $root.CurriculosChanged}"></select>
```

**JS**

```
 function PainelViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Curriculos = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.CurriculoSelected = ko.observable(0);
        self.CurriculosChanged = function (c) {
            console.debug(c.CurriculoSelected);
        };
 }
```

[Check binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Answer (score 1):

First thing first your view model is real messed up. You may need to make changes with variable names used in data-bind to match those in viewmodel. I hope I am getting you right. What you want is to trigger a method when value of combobox changes. For that there is an easier way of using subscribe on an observable(your combobox value). So, whenever value of your combobox changes, subscribe function is triggered. The functionality that you want is passed inside the subscribe function as a function body.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content" id="appGradeHorariaCompleta">
 <select class="form-control m-b" data-bind="options:Curriculos, optionsText:'Text',optionsValue:'Value',optionsCaption:'Selectone', value: CurriculoSelected"></select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function CurriculoViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Curriculos = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.CurriculoSelected = ko.observable('');
    self.CurriculoSelected.subscribe(function(value) {
        // Your change functionality goes here combobox.
    });
}
```

References check out the subscribe:
[Knockout observables subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

[Knockout options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

Comment: I've try this beforne and try again now, but doesn't work. I've read about the subscribe, but for some reason, the subscribe was not triggered when I change value in combobox

Comment: @Adley Here is link to same with use of subscribe:[link](https://jsbin.com/yetefumiku/6/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: I've add this code, but this doesn't work on my project. I forgot to mencion that my project have a lot other scripts using JS and Knockout. I don't really now why, but in this way doesn't work.